# looking for a .JEF embroidery file browser for 64-bit Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I have been looking for a way to view  `.jef` embroidery files in a 64-bit Windows 7 install. the Janome software DOES NOT work on 64-bit, and I get the impression from the forums that they are not planning on making a 64-bit version any time soon.

---

**My question is**: Does anyone know of a `.JEF` viewer for a 64-bit Windows 7 computer.

---

Free / inexpensive would be nice but not required.
I don't want to have to open individual files one at a time to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I found some products, one free and others commercial. They are mostly converters, but these include viewers as well. The commercial ones have trial versions that you can use to evaluate. For most of them, it is unclear from the documentation whether they allow viewing a directory, so one has to try.

[FREE Thread Converter Pro III](http://www.sewingmachinesplus.com/c2s-thread-converter-pro.php)
[SewArt  (various prices with trials)](http://www.stitchesinmotion.ca/collections/software)
[Embrilliance](http://embrilliance.com/)
[Embird](http://www.embird.com/) (costly at $144, but it seems to contain a viewer)

Comment: thanks I will check these out and let you know if they work. (if they work you get the points)

Comment: thanks again for your help but unfortunently NONE of these work...
. Free Threads Converter is a converter which I can't use because I NEED them in the jef format =/

sewwhat just isn't working...idk why

embrilliance I can't find the downoad

and embird requires you turn off UAC which is a NO DEAL PERIOD!

Comment: Embrilliance Essentials is at least [here](http://embrilliance.com/downloads).

Answer (score 1):

According to [a page on Janome's website](http://content.janome.com/index.cfm/LearningCenter/Software_Updates) about Customizer 10000 Plus Version 3.6:

> This update will allow your software to work on a Windows Vista and Windows 7 32/64bit operating system, however, this will not enable the machine driver for the MC10000/10001 to communicate with a 64bit Windows system – the MC10000/10001 will only communicate with a 32bit Windows system.

Although:

> For 64 Bit Users: Please write your designs directly to an ATA/Compact Flash Card no larger than 512mb. Contact your local Janome dealer if you need an ATA/Compact Flash Card and adapter.

There is also a piece of software titled [SewIconz](http://sandscomputing.com/id18.html).

> SewIconz will also display Janome jan files, Viking krz cross stitch and PCStitch pat cross stitch files.

Comment: yah one reason I asked the question is BECAUSE of this janome page... but I will look in to the sewiconz. thanks (I will accept AFTER i try it...)